# where Method outputs empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model by the name of Article and I also have a db table with the name "article".
The article table has a column "created_at".

See image

[image: http://imgur.com/cmu00]

When I run the following command in the console...

```
>> Article.where("created_at < '08-04-2011'")
=> []
```

Does it not say output anything created on dates that are greater than 08-04-2011 (d,m,y)?
Shouldn't this command output the last entry (id #7) you see there in the image posted above?

I've even tried changing the date format around since it doesn't really reflect how it's entered in the db and still not getting the desired results.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
Article.where("created_at < ?" ,  Time.local(2011,4,8))
```

Check: http://railscasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3

Comment: I've tried your command and it outputted an empty array.

I bookmarked the railscasts, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're giving wrong format of the date. Try this instead:

```
>> Article.where("created_at < '2011-04-08 00:00:00'")
```

Comment: I've tried this and it's still outputting an empty array


    => []

Answer (score 0):

I've created a gem that will help with this kind of finding called [by_star](http://github.com/radar/by_star). It may be helpful to you rather than mucking about with how to build these types of queries yourself.